# How to use 2 POM.xml in java maven project

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to implement a project in such a way that, when a specific workflow is initiated one pom (say : pom.xml) should be called and used, if another workflow is initiated use and call pom2.xml.

For e.g: workflow1 from github actions: use pom.xml,
workflow2 from github actions: use pom2.xml

The project and code remains the same but there are certain alterations to the workflows.
Im currently using **mvn clean test** command to invoke a single pom.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a use-case for profiles: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Why do you need two pom files? What are the differences? Please describe more in detail what the differences are? Maybe Profiles could be an answer? But without the context and the differences it's hard to even guess..